# Xcode6 Could not parse server's response as a plist

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, xcode6

I'm trying to add my apple developer account to Xcode Beta 3 so I can run apps in my iPhone, but unsuccessfully. I go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Accounts -> Add Apple ID. Then I enter my user credentials and press OK. I don't think it's a credential issue because entering an incorrect password tells me that the password was rejected, by entering the correct one shows me this:

[image]

Does any one know how to solve this?

Comment: André, please file a radar and report back. We'll look into it.

Comment: @titusmagnus I contacted Apple through Developer Account Assistance, should I still file a bug report?

Comment: I also get this. Perhaps you also have a character that is not a-z in your full name?

Comment: Yes, I have "é". But I already downgraded xcode, so I don't really have a way to test it now...

Comment: Filed a radar: http://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=5263885477085184

Answer (score 21):

Go to appleid.apple.com and remove special character (like e accent "é" ) in your name.

Comment: This issue is still present in BETA 4 as well. The workaround works. But really, Apple. Really!? We don't live in a US ASCII world anymore :/

Comment: Still present in Beta 5 too. Getting the Scandinavian 'ä' into my developer name was actually no small struggle back in 2009, and I'm not exactly eager to give it up now. (I'm lucky enough that my name means something semi-profane in my native language once the diacritics are removed...)

Comment: This answer should be accepted if it helped :) Sure did help me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and the solution was to remove the special characters on my surname