# Unable to add accounts in Xcode 6 beta 6

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, xcode6, account

I've lost my Apple developer account settings in this new Xcode's preferences, so I tried to add it again... I set my account's credentials but I'm not able to sign in, and I always get the message `Could not parse server's response as a plist`

Has anybody found the same problem? This is working fine in Xcode 5.1.1, although I have to add the account again everytime I have previously opened Xcode 6...

Thanks

Comment: Remove any special character, check this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670014/xcode6-could-not-parse-servers-response-as-a-plist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had special characters in my complete name, so I removed them in my profile as pointed out by @vbergae: [Xcode6 Could not parse server's response as a plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24670014/xcode6-could-not-parse-servers-response-as-a-plist)

Now it works