# FIRAuth: An error has occurred while accessing the keychain (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-authentication, swift3

I got stuck on a problem with sign in via Firebase. Everything went ok when it was Swift 2, however after the XCode has converted my whole project to Swift 3 syntax, the error occurred.

Here's my code for login:

```
func loginDidFinish(_ email: String, password: String, type: LoginViewController.SendType) {

        // Server call implementation here
        if type == .login {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    self.alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    self.present(self.alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    let delay = Double(2) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                    let time = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) { [weak self] in
                        self!.alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                } else {

                    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
            })
        } else { // type == .SignUp
            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: password, completion: { (user, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    self.alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    self.present(self.alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                    let delay = Double(2) * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                    let time = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(delay)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
                    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: time) { [weak self] in
                        self!.alert.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
                    }
                } else {

                    _ = self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
                }
            })
        }
```

P.S. Everything is ok when I try to sign up. The user is created, but `popUpViewController` does not work here.

P.P.S. I have already seen similar question ["An error occurred while accessing the keychain" when signing in using Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38538160/an-error-occurred-while-accessing-the-keychain-when-signing-in-using-firebase), but understood nothing from that. Also read this https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/errors.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to solve this:
Go to Project Target -> Capabilities -> Switch On "Keychain Sharing"