# Firebase, Swift : Conflicting nullability specifier on return types, 'nullable' conflicts with existing specifier 'nonnull'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, xcode8

Warning's in **Firebase 3.6.0**. Xcode 8 - Swift 3.

These are the Firebase classes:-

- **`@class FIROptions`**
- **`@class FIRAuthCredential`**
- **`@class FIRUserProfileChangeRequest`**

#### Warning message:

> - (nullable instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;

Figured it might be a bug!.

But if not, any ideas to how to fix it?

Comment: Probably conflicts with some Swift 3 APIs because I'm getting the error too.

Comment: removing nullable annotations would be one of solution. But same issue is reported in https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/issues/166. So, I think that it will be solved as soon as possible.

Comment: Make sure to add `FIRApp.configure()` under `'didFinishLaunchingWithOptions'` method in AppDelegate If you haven't, that may solve the problem.

Answer (score 12):

**Original answer**: This problem is fixed for me as of the latest Firebase (3.7.1). Just do a "pod update Firebase" and then Clean your project (Clean Build Folder via Option key just to be sure).

**Updated answer**: Nope, my bad... the problem remains for me too.

Digging further, there's a good explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39233507/3638762

In the meantime (since I felt bad about getting your hopes up) I found a nice way to suppress the warning. I had to guess at the -Wnullability warning type. ;-)

Add these three #pragma lines around the offending line in Pods/FirebaseCore/Frameworks/FirebaseCore.framework/Headers/FIRApp.h:

```
#pragma clang diagnostic push
#pragma clang diagnostic ignored "-Wnullability"
- (nullable instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE;
#pragma clang diagnostic pop
```

Cheers!

Comment: I don't know why but i still get these warnings

Comment: Same here even with the 3.7.1 version.

Comment: Me too! I've updated my answer with a convenient workaround until the problem gets fixed.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this warby.  My issue is that I cannot do a Whole Module Optimization because of this error, as Ken Tan mentions.  Even with this workaround it still does not work for me.

Comment: This helped me use AFNetworking 2.0 (without warnings) too ... Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity -> change debug and release to iOS Developer.

Answer (score 1):

While waiting for Firebase team to resolve this bug, you may consider to change `Swift Optimization Level` in `Build Settings` to `None`.

Take note that this is a temporary workaround. Please switch it back to `Fast, Whole Module Optimization` after Firebase has released a fix.

Comment: You might prefer the workaround in my answer as it only affects the one offending line rather than the entire project.

Comment: XCode gave me the option to edit the locked file and the edit worked.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I went to Build Settings -> Code Signing Identity -> change debug and release to iOS Developer.

Answer (score 1):

Go to your Pods -> Build Settings -> Use Legacy Swift Language Version and se it to No, this worked for me.

Clean your project and build.

I was able to reproduce the warnings and fix on multiple occasions.

Answer (score 0):

it is solved by firebase 4.0.4, just be sure to write "FirebaseApp.configure()" in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions function in the app delegate, instead of the old one "FIRApp.configure()"

good luck

Answer (score -1):

Clearing derived data folder and cleaning seemed to make these errors disappear for me.  If you are seeing " STOP!! Will reset deviceID from memory." as well, enable Keychain Sharing in Capabilities.

Comment: It doesn't work at my side. It seems more like a Firebase bug after the Swift 3.0 update.