# Xcode 8 - Command failed due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I just migrated my project to `Swift 3.0` using `Xcode 8`.  The app is working fine on a device and in the simulator.  However, when I archive it in preparation to upload to app store I get stuck with the error:

> Command failed due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4

I have cleaned the build and removed the derived data folder. CocoaPods installations are up-to-date.  I tried commenting out all code related to dictionaries that was the solution to [this similar Xcode 7 issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821771/xcode-7-command-failed-due-to-signal-illegal-instruction-4), but I still get the error.

In case it's helpful the full error print out is below.  I'm not sure how to interpret this to pinpoint the location of the issue better.

**Edit:**

The ResultsTableViewCell file is the last one in this long list.  Perhaps that is where the issue?  An earlier line in the error code below calls out the following about that file:

/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/ResultsTableViewCell.swift -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk

It's the only on that talks about ios9.0 target.  The file itself is just for a simple xib.  I'm going to try to explore around this file and xib more. This could also just be the last file listed because all of them are listed in this error print out.

Anyways, besides that lead, I'm completely stuck at this point and unsure how to proceed to diagnose the issue.  Any thoughts and help are greatly appreciated.

---

> CompileSwift normal arm64
>       cd /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift
>   -frontend -emit-bc /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/ForgotPasswordViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/DetailedResultWebViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/SearchHistoryModel.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/SearchHistoryViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PersonalDemographics.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/RecommendationModel.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/Recommendation.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/AdditionalPersonalCharacteristicsViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/DetailedResultsViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/LoginViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PersonalPsychographics.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/BottomNavigationBar.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/RegisterViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/ProfileViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PersonalOther.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PersonalActivity.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PersonalFood.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PsychographicsViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/Extensions.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PageViewControllerHolder.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/AppDelegate.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/MainSearchViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PersonalPets.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/ContactUsViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/UserInformation.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/ResultsViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/EnterNewPasswordViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/SearchLocationResultsController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PhotoViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/PersonalNumberChildren.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/InstructionsViewController.swift
>   /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/ResultsTableViewCell.swift
>   -target arm64-apple-ios9.0 -Xllvm -aarch64-use-tbi -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS10.0.sdk
>   -I /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/FirebaseAuth/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/FirebaseDatabase/Frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/FirebaseStorage/Frameworks/frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/GoogleInterchangeUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/GoogleMaps/Subspecs/Base/Frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/GoogleMaps/Subspecs/Maps/Frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/GoogleNetworkingUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/GooglePlaces/Frameworks -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/GoogleSymbolUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/GoogleUtilities/Frameworks
>   -F /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado -g -import-objc-header /Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Funyado/Funyado-Bridging-Header.h
>   -module-cache-path /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache
>   -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Funyado-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Funyado-own-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Funyado-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/all-product-headers.yaml
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Funyado-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Firebase/Analytics/Sources -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/Firebase -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAnalytics
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseAuth
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseDatabase
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseInstanceID
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/FirebaseStorage
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleInterchangeUtilities
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleMaps -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleNetworkingUtilities
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/GooglePlaces
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleSymbolUtilities
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado/Pods/Headers/Public/GoogleUtilities
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/DerivedSources/arm64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/AppleComputer/Desktop/Funyado -emit-module-doc-path /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Funyado.swiftdoc
>   -O -module-name Funyado -emit-module-path /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Funyado.swiftmodule
>   -emit-objc-header-path /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Funyado-Swift.h
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ForgotPasswordViewController.dia
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ForgotPasswordViewController.d
>   -num-threads 4 -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ForgotPasswordViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DetailedResultWebViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SearchHistoryModel.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SearchHistoryViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PersonalDemographics.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RecommendationModel.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Recommendation.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AdditionalPersonalCharacteristicsViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/DetailedResultsViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/LoginViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PersonalPsychographics.bc -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/BottomNavigationBar.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/RegisterViewController.bc -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ProfileViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PersonalOther.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PersonalActivity.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PersonalFood.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PsychographicsViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/Extensions.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PageViewControllerHolder.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/AppDelegate.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/MainSearchViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PersonalPets.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ContactUsViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/UserInformation.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ResultsViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/EnterNewPasswordViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/SearchLocationResultsController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PhotoViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/PersonalNumberChildren.bc -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/InstructionsViewController.bc
>   -o /Users/AppleComputer/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Funyado-ehusaveyfxvoqqhkifknkgpejzbx/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/Funyado/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/Funyado.build/Release-iphoneos/Funyado.build/Objects-normal/arm64/ResultsTableViewCell.bc

Comment: I had a similar issue happen to me recently after migrating my project to `Swift 3`. I ended up commenting out my entire VC then running the app to see if everything works. Then I slowly started uncommenting one method at a time and at times even re-writing them so as I may see if there were any signature changes in `Swift 3`.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts Emil.  Did you have a way to figure out which VC was causing the issue or you just went through them one by one?  Sounds like fun.  Haha.

Comment: Not really..Just like you, one VC stood out and it was listed all the way at the bottom. So for your case I'd recommend you start with `ResultsTableViewCell` because it's the one that seems to be missing its binary file.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around solution.  Under Build Settings and Optimization Level, I changed the Optimization Level to "Fast, Single File Optimization" instead of "Fast, Whole Module Optimization".  After doing that it successfully compiled and I could upload it to the app store.

The reason that the app was working for me in the simulator and on my device was because by default the optimization level for Debug is set to "None".

It's not ideal, but given that Swift 3 is so new, and that this might be a bug or something I could more easily fix in future with updates, this route will do for now.

Comment: I believe I've diagnosed the issue to be related to Firebase and what's being described in this Q&A.  None of the solutions here worked for me though and I still have the optimization level set to Single File Optimization.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39564164/firebase-swift-conflicting-nullability-specifier-on-return-types-nullable