# Realm for Swift 3.1 - Command failed due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4

Tags: swift, realm, swift3

After updating Swift to v3.1, I got Realm frameworks replaced by the new version downloaded from [Realm Swift 2.5.1](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/) but get the following issue:

> Command failed due to signal: Illegal instruction: 4

Already checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30821771/xcode-7-command-failed-due-to-signal-illegal-instruction-4) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39628907/xcode-8-command-failed-due-to-signal-illegal-instruction-4), but they didn't work.

Here is the error description, not sure if it's helpful though.

> CompileSwift normal x86_64
>   /Users/linhcn/Documents/XcodeProjects/HerdManager/HerdManager/Models/ActionCategory.swift
>   -target x86_64-apple-ios9.3 -enable-objc-interop -sdk /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator10.3.sdk
>   -I /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator
>   -F /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/FileBrowser
>   -F /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Realm
>   -F /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RealmSwift
>   -F /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/Toast-Swift
>   -F /Users/linhcn/Documents/XcodeProjects/HerdManager/HerdManager/Frameworks
>   -enable-testing -g -module-cache-path /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ModuleCache -D DEBUG
>   -D COCOAPODS -serialize-debugging-options -Xcc -I/Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/swift-overrides.hmap
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/HerdManager-generated-files.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/HerdManager-own-target-headers.hmap -Xcc -I/Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/HerdManager-all-non-framework-target-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -ivfsoverlay -Xcc /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/all-product-headers.yaml
>   -Xcc -iquote -Xcc /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/HerdManager-project-headers.hmap
>   -Xcc -I/Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/include
>   -Xcc -I/Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/DerivedSources/x86_64
>   -Xcc -I/Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/DerivedSources
>   -Xcc -DDEBUG=1 -Xcc -DCOCOAPODS=1 -Xcc -working-directory/Users/linhcn/Documents/XcodeProjects/HerdManager -emit-module-doc-path /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Invoice~partial.swiftdoc
>   -serialize-diagnostics-path /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Invoice.dia
>   -Onone -module-name HerdManager -emit-module-path /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Invoice~partial.swiftmodule
>   -emit-dependencies-path /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Invoice.d
>   -emit-reference-dependencies-path /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Invoice.swiftdeps
>   -o /Users/linhcn/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/HerdManager-exytfaymknfhzqabpximiccdzmaa/Build/Intermediates/HerdManager.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/HerdManager.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Invoice.o

Comment: share full error

Comment: realm buggy for swift3.1

Comment: Please file an issue on realm-cocoa by going here: https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/new and please fill out the issue template to provide as much information as possible.

Comment: @WillowPuge did it a few days ago https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4841

Comment: The link is broken?

Comment: @WillowPuge My github account was flagged. I contact them for support. Thanks

Comment: Please refer to this link https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/issues/4841 It's working now

Comment: No worries! We'll be in touch on GitHub. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem solved.**

I guess that it's a problem of the new Xcode's (8.3.2) error report system. Apple may add some new coding rules but not update the error reporter. I ended up commenting out all the code and uncommenting each part to figure out where the problem is. It reports errors in some classes but the actual problem is in another class.