# Conflicting Nullability

Tags: firebase

I'm using `Firebase` in a Swift project. I see many errors for within the Firebase framework, all on this:

```
- (nullable instancetype)init NS_UNAVAILABLE 
// WARNING: Conflicting nullability specifier on return types, 'nullable' conflicts with existing specifier 'nonnull'
```

With a bit of research, it seems this SO post has a possible [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164411/xcode-8-0-beta-give-an-error-after-import-firebase).

Turning on **Keychain Sharing** seems to remove the warnings. Though, this feels like a bandaid fix; Firebase never mentioned the need for Keychain Sharing.

I'm wondering if anyone knows why turning **Keychain Sharing** would remove the warnings, and whether that is a good idea or not.