# <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Unable to generate key pair

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i have a strange message in console from FirebaseSDK iOS.

After this message :

STOP!! Will reset deviceID from memory. Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"

STOP!! Will reset deviceID from memory.
 Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"

Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"
 Failed to retrieve the default GCM token after 5 retries

I already enable Keychain capabilities to on in the project.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164411/xcode-8-0-beta-give-an-error-after-import-firebase

Answer (score 2):

This simply means that your Keychain Sharing is off by default in your Capabilities.

Simply go to your Target Project in the navigator and then in the capabilities tab scroll down to Keychain Sharing and switch it to ON, this should fix it for you.