# Firebase error creating a register and login

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-authentication

I have followed this tutorial:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OaiLpVG6Tlc

correctly (or so I believe), however I get [these errors](http://pastebin.com/uduLCTeK) on launch:

> 2016-09-07 20:36:05.520: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"
>   2016-09-07 20:36:15.743 customLogin[833:] <FIRAnalytics/WARNING> Failed to get InstanceID: Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=-34018 "(null)"
>   2016-09-07 20:36:19.504: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"
>   2016-09-07 20:36:46.642: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"
>   2016-09-07 20:37:28.821: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"
>   2016-09-07 20:38:31.108: <FIRInstanceID/WARNING> Failed to fetch default token Error Domain=com.firebase.iid Code=6 "(null)"

How can I fix this?

When I try and press the login button or create account button on my app I also get this error:

> "An error occurred when accessing the keychain".

Comment: Did you try [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456471/secitemadd-always-returns-error-34018-in-xcode-8-beta-4-in-ios-10-simulator) or one of the other [results in this list](https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+%22An+error+occured+when+accessing+the+keychain)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Enable this from firebase
[image]

// For Firebase Login code :

```
@IBAction func OnLoginButtonClicked(sender: AnyObject) {

FIRAuth.auth()?.signInWithEmail(Username.text!, password: Password.text!, completion: {

    user , error in
            if error != nil {

                print("Wrong Password ")
            }
            else {
               print("Login Successfully :)")
                 }
    })
```

// Create For New Account

```
@IBAction func OnCreateButtonClicked(sender:AnyObject){

    FIRAuth.auth()?.createUserWithEmail(Username.text!, password: Password.text!, completion: {
      user , error in

        if error != nil {

            print("Account Does't Created ! Something went to Wrong !")
        }

        else {

            print("Account Created Successfully :)")

        }
```

})

Answer (score 8):

Try going to your Target > Capabilities, and setting Keychain Sharing to On.