# Unable to store data in Keychain Xcode 8 GM (Swift 3)

Tags: ios, keychain, swift3, xcode8

In my project I need to save some data in Keychain, hence I'm using some open-source, but the data is not getting stored in keychain. I have tried many open source,  in every open source the attempt to store data in keychain failed.

Used Keychain open sources:

KeyClip - https://github.com/s-aska/KeyClip

Keychain - https://github.com/marketplacer/keychain-swift

keychain access - https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess

Comment: Xcode 8 is full of bug and this too is bug I think

Comment: does it fail at SecItemAdd? if so see http://stackoverflow.com/q/38456471/2237587

Comment: Why are you using Xcode 8 GM instead of the release?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Enable KeyChain sharing** in **Capabilities** which downloads an entitlement files.Clean and run the project now data gets stored in Keychain.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using xCode 8.0 please do below :

```
Project Navigator -> Select Target -> Capabilities 

Enable KeyChain Sharing ON
```

[image]