# Saving Data persistently into KeychainAccess in Swift 5.0

Tags: swift, keychain, saving-data

I want to save sensitive user data into Keychain persistently but problem is, every time I re-launch the app in both of simulator and a device I am loosing all the data. As per my understanding keychained data should keep living in the system unless explicitly removing it. I know how to save data in the file with file manager but this would not be appropriate for this service. I have tried to find answer but no luck. I am specifically looking for "Saving Data into Keychain" and "Keep This Data Persistently so that When Removing and Re-launching App Data is Still There". FYI, I am now using KeychainAccess wrapper (https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/KeychainAccess).

Please help me save the data with keychain persistently.
App I am working on stores sensitive data so believe it should be keychain, but you can suggest any other if more proper.

Belows are my testing code to achieve consistent saving but no luck.

1. This is a keychaining functions with a wrapped called KeychainAccess

```
import Foundation
import KeychainAccess

class Retriever {

    static let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.cochipcho.KeeperApp")

    // store
    static func saveToKeychain(data: Data) {
        keychain[data: "encoded"] = NSData(data: data) as Data

    }
    //retrieve
    static func loadFromKeychain() -> [String] {
        let retrievedData = keychain[data: "encoded"]
        let string = try? NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveTopLevelObjectWithData(retrievedData!) as? [String]
        return string!
    }

}
```

This is a view controller declaring to save/retrieve data from keychain class.

```
import UIKit
import KeychainAccess

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    var array = [String]()

//saving into keychain
    @IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        array.append(textField.text!)
        let data = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedData(withRootObject: array)
        Retriever.saveToKeychain(data: data)
        }

//retrieving from keychain
    @IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!
    @IBAction func retrieveButton(_ sender: Any) {
        label.text = "\(Retriever.loadFromKeychain())"
        print(Retriever.loadFromKeychain())
        print(Retriever.keychain[data: "encoded"])
    }
}
```

Below in a console that's saving input data - but it is all gone once re-install and re-launch app on simulator.

```
["1"]
Optional(227 bytes)
["1", "2"]
Optional(235 bytes)
["1", "2"]
Optional(235 bytes)
["1", "2", "3"]
Optional(243 bytes)
["1", "2", "3", "4"]
Optional(251 bytes)
["1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]
Optional(259 bytes)
```

Comment: Your code should work. If the items that were saved disappear after re-launch, probably you clear the keychain items somewhere? Can you share a reproducible sample project for further investigation?

Comment: Thank you Kishikawa for checking, will let you see the full code as soon as it's ready to be inspected:)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I had to set KeyChain sharing in Capabilities and downloads entitlements. After setting it things go well. Here goes a link that helped me.

[Unable to store data in Keychain Xcode 8 GM (Swift 3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39532818/unable-to-store-data-in-keychain-xcode-8-gm-swift-3)

Also, this is another issue I had when working on my actual project. Whilst the code above is taking Arrays which was encoded/decoded with NSKeyedArchiver, my project takes custom class types and didn't work on NSKeyedArchiver. Instead I tried PropertyList to encode/decode it and it is finally working. I successfully encoded/decoded/keychained. Please see below working code.

```
import Foundation
import KeychainAccess

class UserInformation: Codable {
    var isExpanded: Bool
    var isPinned: Bool
    var sectionName: String
    var userInformation: [String?]
    var indexPathSection: Int?

    init(isExpanded: Bool, isPinned: Bool, sectionName: String, userInformation: [String?], indexPathSection: Int?) {
        self.isExpanded = isExpanded
        self.isPinned = isPinned
        self.sectionName = sectionName
        self.userInformation = userInformation
        self.indexPathSection = indexPathSection
    }

}

extension UserInformation {
    static let propertyListEncoder = PropertyListEncoder()
    static let propertyListDecoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    static let keychain = Keychain(service: "com.cochipcho.KeeperApp-UserInfo")

    static func saveToKeychain(userInfo: [UserInformation]) {
        let data = try? propertyListEncoder.encode(userInfo)
        if let savingData = data {
            keychain[data: "encodedUserInfo"] = NSData(data: savingData) as Data
        }
    }

    static func loadFromKeychain() -> [UserInformation]? {
        guard let retrievedData = keychain[data: "encodedUserInfo"] else { return nil }
        let data = try? propertyListDecoder.decode(Array<UserInformation>.self, from: retrievedData)
        return data
    }

}
```

One concerned remained - is PropertyListEncoder/PropertyList good choice here? I think I am not storing any data but just encoding/decoding the custom types with PropertyListEncoder, then keep them in Keychain, so I think it is secure. Please anyone knows about it help advise?