# IOS 10 trouble with KeyChain

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, keychain, ios10

Since the IOS 10 update I had great difficulties with my app and so far I haven´t been able to find any clue on what he problem could be.

I´m using a framework called SimpleKayChain for storing login details for users. 
It´s been working great until now. But after the IOS 10 updates all my stored KeyChains are returning NULL. 
https://github.com/auth0/SimpleKeychain/blob/master/SimpleKeychain/A0SimpleKeychain.h

For Saving KeyChain

```
[[A0SimpleKeychain keychain] setString:token forKey:tokenConstant];
```

For returning KeyChain

```
NSString *token = [[A0SimpleKeychain keychain] stringForKey:tokenConstant];
```

I would really appreciate some directions regarding how to solve this.
Thanks.

Comment: iam not sure why, but for me it was only working with iPhone 7 Simulator.  I made as well my Project signed with provisioning profiles and so on

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the latest iOS 10 simulators. This issue does not affect real devices - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456471/secitemadd-always-returns-error-34018-in-xcode-8-in-ios-10-simulator

Comment: strange, i lost 2 hours today for this ... on my Mac it was working but on the CI server not ... funny

Comment: Try enabling shared keychain. The keychain has been very buggy for me since Beta 1.

Comment: Thanks! The simulator and KeyChains started to work again after I enabled shared KeyChain just as you said. Very strange bugg.