# LayerKit connection error "Generation of key pair failed with result code -34018"

Tags: ios, objective-c, layer, atlas, layerkit

I am getting an error while connecting LYRClient as "Generation of key pair failed with result code -34018"

I followed the link asking to update sdk version below but its also not working.

https://support.layer.com/hc/en-us/articles/206437643-I-get-a-Generation-of-key-pair-failed-with-result-code-34018-error-when-trying-to-connect-to-Layer

Currently I am using Layerkit version 0.23.3 but still i am getting same error.

Can anyone please help here ?
Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456471/secitemadd-always-returns-error-34018-in-xcode-8-in-ios-10-simulator

Comment: Yeah it works
Thanks