# Xcode8 : Failed to remove keychain items

Tags: xcode8

When I run the app on my phone it works all right, but when I run it on the simulator I get this error:

[image]

I don't know what can I do for this. What is wrong?

Comment: I am having the same issue. For me it seems to be my use of a keychain sharing group. The keychain group for the main app is `com.company.AppName` and my share extension is set to the same `com.company.AppName`. But if I allow the extension to use `com.company.AppName.Share` it seems to work in the simulator but then I am unable to share the keychain properly between the extension and the app.

Comment: Try enabling Keychain Access Groups. [More here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38456471/secitemadd-always-returns-error-34018-in-xcode-8-in-ios-10-simulator)

Comment: Also update your system and xcode to newest versions.

Comment: thank you for your help. i remember that i try to save/read uuid by keychain on simulator.may be in taht way the  simulator can’t be working…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to go to the simulator and long press the icon of the app you are trying to run. Then press the small x on the top right of the app to delete it.

Run the app again and you are fine!

Comment: @user7563640 :)