# IOS KeyChainWrapper value is nil after stored

Tags: ios, swift

Im a beginner in Swift 3.0. Recently i just convert existing swift project to 3.0 swift. After converrted, i have issues storing user& password using key chain wrapper.

i have checked the result of Bool, it just show false and the value is nil.

Can i know the possible causes? thanks for guiding.

```
//This is how i store
var saveSuccessful:Bool = KeychainWrapper.defaultKeychainWrapper().setString(txt_userId.text!, forKey: "userId")
    let savePass:Bool = KeychainWrapper.setString(txt_password.text!, forKey: "password")

 //this is how i get/retrieve
 var password:String? = KeychainWrapper.stringForKey("password")
```

Comment: you are using some library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27752444/ios-keychain-writing-value-results-in-error-code-34018/40125461#40125461). The problem is that the "Keychain Sharing" capability has to be enabled.